# Fill column if other columns in row are not empty

Tags: vba, excel

**Using**:

1. Microsoft Office Excel Macro-Enabled Worksheet 2007
2. Microsoft Visual Basic

I've been searching on ways to resolve my issue and couldn't really find the key to resolve this.

### Case

In a worksheet I need to automatically insert a value (static timestamp) into column right after specified range of columns based on condition that they are all not null (have been filled).

### Example goal

Given the order of inserting values into rows one after another, when values in range of columns `A:C` are filled, I'd want the column `D` (the next one after specified range) to update.

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC AutoInsert
filled  filled  filled  2016-01-11 20:57
filled  filled      
filled          
filled  filled  filled  2016-01-11 20:58
```

### What have I got?

Right now when I insert value into column `A` current timestamp appears in column `B`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
            With Target(1, 2)
                .Value = Now
            End With
        End If
End Sub
```

Current results:

```
ColumnA AutoInsert
value   2016-01-11 21:06
value   2016-01-11 21:06
value   2016-01-11 21:07
```

### What do I need?

I need some way to check for specified range of columns within row, not only the first column like shown above *(in **what have I got?** section).*

I'm not sure whether I need some other method than `Intersect`, or some kind of a loop. I've tried experimenting with `Target(x, y)` and `Range("A:C")`, but the behavior is different than expected and seems to be applied to each active cell.

Comment: Range("a" & target.row).value<>"" and range("b" & target.row).value<>"" etc, sorry on tablet :-)

Comment: @Nathan_Sav thanks for your suggestion. I will remember that as an option :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
            If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:C")) Is Nothing And WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Range("A" & Target.Row & ":C" & Target.Row)) = 0 Then
                With Me.Cells(Target.Row, 4)
                    Application.EnableEvents = False
                    .value = Now
                End With
            End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The `Me` refers to the sheet.  It works because this is a worksheet event.  If this was in a module it would need to be `ActiveSheet`.  The `.Cells` is a Range.  It used in this format `Cells(Row,Column)`. The whole thing could have been rewritten as `Me.Range("D" & Target.row)`.

Target is a range and doing `Target(row,column)` is shorthand for `Target.Cells(row,column)`  You could have put `Target(1,4)`.  `Target(1,1)` would have referred to itself, or the upper left cell in a range of cells.  It is not constrained by the range but uses the upper left cell as a starting point.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Could you please edit your answer and explain the use of `Me.Cells` and why `Target` is not valid? I'm a newbie considering VBA. I'd greatly appreciate that.

Comment: Could I get some insight about when `EnableEvents` would make a difference in this scenario?

Comment: @ConsiderMe It controls whether other events fire or not.  so in this case, when the code puts a value in column D it would fire the worksheet_change event again.  Not in this case, but it could start a infinite loop, so it is good practice to turn it off and back on again.  It does not get into an infinite loop here because it tests whether the change was in columns A - C to do anything.

Comment: Exactly what I though it meant. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: Would it matter if `EnableEvents` was set to `False` between two `Ifs` ? I think not, but am unsure. This way it would be set after the first possible `Exit` from `Sub` and before the actual start of the code.

Comment: You can set it anywhere you want. but make sure that **before exiting the sub it gets turned back on**.  The reason that Jeeped put it after the If in this instance was there is no reason for it till right before the change to column D to turn it off.  If it gets turned off it stays off till it gets turned on again.  There have been times that took me hours to figure out that I had turned it off and could get not get the code to run properly.